# Call and Save Returned Value from Method in React

Tags: web3js, react

I am trying to call a method from my smart contract (myMethod) and save the result (result) as a state (this.state.result) in react. However, my state is not being updated to the result. My code is provided below. How can I fix this?

```
      await this.contractInstance.methods.myMethod().call({from: this.account, gas: 5000000}).then(result => {return this.state.result = result}).catch('That's a RIP');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly.

For example, this will not re-render a component:

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';
```

Instead, use [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
// Correct
this.setState({ comment: 'Hello' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but in my case i had an angular project and it didn't update my attribut so i had to create my instance of State in your case inside the function that returns the result.